# Begin a storyboard on loaded event in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, prism

I am looking at the Prism Stocktrader RI and I can see that the InTransition Storyboard is played using code. I tried the following xaml:

```
    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UserControl.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource InTransition}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>
```

But it gives the following error on InitializeComponent (i.e. a XamlParseException):
[image]

 any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think triggers are not available in Silverlight.

You can use a **ControlStoryboardAction** behavior to call a storyboard in xaml, like the following (you will need Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll and System.Windows.Interactivity.dll),

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource InTransition}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Note: you can remove EventName='Loaded' as 'Loaded' is the default event for this control.

Comment: +1 Absolutely right, Triggers are a WPF concept.  The StockTrader RI application the OP mentioned is indeed WPF.  ControlStoryBoardAction Behavior is the way to go for Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for such errors there's an Inner Exception. Please do "View Detail" and check on that for us.

The error generally means it couldn't resolve the resource correctly, so you might need to look at what `InTransition` is (please post that if this doesn't help you)